# Android - Grabbing an image from a URL and displaying it in an ImageView with an AsyncTask

Tags: android, image, url, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get the app to show an image from a URL, im fairly certain the issue is with the AsyncTask but I've returned to this code several times over the past week and I still cant see where I'm going wrong.

The Internet permission is set and I am getting no LogCat

```
ImageView eventImage2;
eventImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eventImage2);

new imageupdate().execute();

public class imageupdate extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... url) {


        URL url1;

        try {


            url1 = new URL("http://masterzangetsu.eu/Apps/NowIGetYou/banner.png");
            HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();

            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return img;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute(String result) {


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        eventImage2.setImageBitmap(result);

    }

}
```

As far as I can tell the img variable defined with the

```
img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

isnt being linked to the variable being returned

```
return img;
```

Both variables result and img are coming back as null

Comment: You set `result` to `null` then use `img = result`...this will mean that `img` is `null`. Did you mean to switch around `img` and `result`?

Comment: Did you try to debug this code, to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: @codeMagic just swapped it still same issue

Comment: You can't use `Toast` in `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
  Bitmap result = null;

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 


        img = result;
```

to

```
  Bitmap img = null;

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 


        result = img;
```

and `return result` in `doInBackground()`. You have them switched around so 'img' will be `null` no matter what happens.

Also, you can't use `Toast` in `doInBackground()` as this method isn't run on the `UI` thread. You will need to make that a `Log` or put your `Toast` in `onPostExecute()` or `onProgressUpdate()`. These are the things I see. If you are still having problems then you need to be a little more clear on what specifically. You will need to debug and use breakpoints to see what isn't being returned that should be and pinpoint a little more what the problem is

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - any `UI` updates must be done in one of the other methods of `AsyncTask` other than `doInBackground()` or you can pass a value back to the `Activity` to update the `UI` there.